# Understanding Lambda in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

I'm studying for a test, and looking at some of the old tests we've been given, there's a lot of trick questions where you're given a confusing looking scheme code featuring lambda and you need to state what it outputs. Seems simple enough if you understand lambda, but after reading a bunch of scheme tutorials/lessons, I still can't seem to crack these questions. Here are some examples:

```
(define y 10)

((lambda (x y)
   (x (x (x y y) y) y))
 (lambda (x y)
   (+ x y))
 7)
```

outputs 28.

```
(define (f x y) (* 5 (+ x y)))
((lambda (y x z)
   (f y (x y z)))
 10
 *
 3)
```

outputs 200.

Can someone walk me through either one or both of these examples, and explain HOW we get those answers? I've been racking my brains trying to understand this. I've been dissecting these problems on Racket to see if I can get a better understanding, but no luck. I went and created an account just to ask this.

Comment: Try using Racket's debugger, it'll go through each step. Far more illustrative than having it explained in words ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the first example:

The procedure `(lambda (x y) (x (x (x y y) y) y))` is passed 2 parameters x  and y: `x` will be bound to `(lambda (x y) (+ x y))`, and `y` will be bound to 7.

Start by substituting `y` by 7 yields the following (I've taken the liberty to change `x` to `f` because I find it shows better that the parameter is a function/procedure):

```
((lambda (f) (f (f (f 7 7) 7) 7))
 (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
```

Now, the inner `(f 7 7)` evaluates to `(+ 7 7)` hence 14. Continuing the substitution this gives `(f (f 14 7) 7))` then `(f 21 7)` and finally 28.

Comment: Thanks! So what's the deal with the (define y 10) at the top? I'm not used to ever seeing define without a function name in parenthesis after it, so what exactly does that part mean? And also, is the 10 just a decoy? What's the point of having the 10? Well, it is a part of a test so it could easily be a decoy, but does it actually serve any purpose as far as syntax goes?

Comment: That value of `y` would be used if `y` was a "free" variable somewhere in the code but it isn't. If you run the code without that `define` the result is exactly the same. So yes it's a decoy here.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "In computer programming, the term free variable refers to variables used in a function that are neither local variables nor parameters of that function. The term non-local variable is often a synonym in this context." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble rewrite the lambdas as defines

```
;; original
(define y 10)

((lambda (x y)
   (x (x (x y y) y) y))
 (lambda (x y)
   (+ x y))
 7)

;; could be rewritten with defines as
(define y 10)

(define f
  (lambda (x y)
   (x (x (x y y) y) y))

(define g
  (lambda (x y)
     (+ x y))

(f g 7)
```

Using substitution in the rewrite, it's quite simple to follow the code

```
;; g and 7 are applied to f   
(f g 7)
(g (g (g 7 7) 7) 7)

;; 7 and 7 are applied to g
(+ 7 7)
14

;; which gives us
(g (g 14 7) 7)

;; 14 and 7 are applied to g
(+ 14 7)
21

;; which gives us
(g 21 7)

;; lastly, 21 and 7 are applied to g
(+ 21 7)
28
```

You can use this identical approach to evaluating the other lambda expression

---

Another approach would  be to notice that

```
(lambda (x y) (+ x y))
```

is the same as

```
+
```

Which means you can rewrite the entire problem as

```
((lambda (x y)
   (x (x (x y y) y) y))
 +
 7)
```

Then using substitution

```
(+ (+ (+ 7 7) 7) 7)
(+ (+ 14 7) 7)
(+ 21 7)
28
```

---

> **Warning:** the `(define y 10)` is a red herring. That value will not be used as each lambda uses a bound `y` variable and the outer `y` (`10`) is never used.

Comment: One note. That `(lambda (x y) (+ x y))` is not exactly the same as `+` since `+` is variadic (i.e. can take 0 or more arguments) while that lambda is a simple lambda taking two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The second one.

```
(define (f x y) (* 5 (+ x y)))
((lambda (y x z)
   (f y (x y z)))
 10
 *
 3)
```

First `lambda` is solved. In that procedure is `(y x z)` call is defined by `(f y (x y z))`. And the call is `(10 * 3)`.

So `(f y (x y z))` becomes `(f 10 (* 10 3))`. Solving the inside `()` first, we get `(f 10 30)`.

Then applying procedure `f` we get, `(* 5 (+ 10 30))`, solving the inside `()`, we get `(* 5 40)`, and then finally solving the outer `()`, we get `200`.